# Character coding problem

Tags: php, centos

I have a file named index.php which using a mysql server gets a simple username. The mysql server is running on centOS and I have two different systems running apache serving as web servers.

One is my own windows pc using a "wamp" solution which uses the mysql server refereed before and the other is the centOS server itself.

I use this so I can develop in my laptop and run the final on the centOS box.

The problem is this:

Accessing centOS box I get (on hxxp://centos):

```
out_sider 1lu�s 2oi
```

Using wamp on windows I get (on hxxp://localhost):

```
out_sider 1luís 2oi
```

The mysql database is configured correctly seeing that both use the same and I used svn repository to move files from windows to centOS so the file is the same.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advnce

Answer (score 0):

Check fonts and encodings -- specify a Unicode font.

Comment: Where exactly? php file or mysql? thx for the reply
I already tried setting utf8 with dreamwever

Comment: In the CentOS environment.  I'm assuming the Windows quote is what you want to get.  Make sure the font being used by the CentOS application supports Unicode.